# Updating Default preferences

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

I have an issue, i have to set a whole host of settings prior to running my main app. These are done through an on-boarding process, however this is not being reflected in my main settings once in the main app.

During on-boarding i set:

```
       radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                int radioId = checkedId;
                radioButton = getActivity().findViewById(radioId);
                String str = (String) radioButton.getText();
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyApplication.getAppContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(kDirection, str).apply();
                editor.commit();
            }
        });
```

My Preference:

```
    <PreferenceCategory app:title="Directions">

        <ListPreference
            app:key="kDirectionSetting"
            app:entryValues="@array/directions"
            android:entries="@array/directions"
            app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"
            app:title="Direction Preference"
            />

    </PreferenceCategory>
```

This is reflected in my preferences If i open them in device file explorer before i open the preferences screen. Then when the main menu is opened and the preference screen loaded the String is changed to an unset default value from my array, the same every time.

How do i get the reflected changes to show in my settings first time?

Comment: `During on-boarding` ? What is 'on-boarding'?

Comment: What is 'kDirection'?

Comment: `String str = (String) radioButton.getText()` Well what is the text? And what does it have to do with your list preference?

Comment: Your list preference has no devault value or index.

Comment: @blackapps So on-boarding is the process of getting user information during the initial installation and first use of the App.

Comment: @blackapps In this case the example i have given the user is offered a list of radio buttons with which they indicate the units they would like direction measured in. Upon choosing the option the str String which represents the choice is saved to default preferences. When this process is complete the main app screen becomes available with a menu link to the users settings where this along with other settings can be edited.

Comment: @blackapps However if say "degrees" was chosen during the on-boarding once in the settings menu of the main screen the directions option is still "Radians"... as an example. once the setting is changed back to "degrees" via the this page it is committed and persists. Hope that makes sense. I need the initial choice to be reflected in the settings when they first open them. Had to split my answer up do to the character limit.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you have the same key for both your ListPreference and the initial Preference value that you stored, then you will get the ListPreference to edit the initial value. However, do this to set the default value to the ListPreference:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ListPreference kDirectionPref = (ListPreference) findPreference("kDirectionSetting");
    kDirectionPref.setDefaultValue(prefs.getString("kDirection"));
```

So basically, what I'm saying is that you should ensure that you use the same key to put values for your Preference, i.e. in the first piece of code, `kDirection` should be changed to `"kDirectionSetting"`.